# Adding new address to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I can't see my home address on Google Maps as it is a new neighbourhood.

How can I get my home address added into Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for and use Google Mapmaker
https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker

To Add an address:

1. Click Add New and select Add a Place from the drop-down menu.
2. Zoom in and drop the marker at the exact location.
3. Select the category Address from the drop-down menu.
4. Enter the address in the left panel.
5. Click Save to finish.

---

Following the link above reports that:

> **Google Map Maker has closed**
>
> Google Map Maker officially closed on March 31, 2017, and many of its
>   features are being integrated into Google Maps.