# Set my Home location on Google Maps, if it does not have an official/registered address?

Tags: google-maps, select-by-location

The answer to ["Adding new address to Google Maps?"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208513/adding-new-address-to-google-maps) does not include a case for non-business addresses. I want to add my home address, which is not a register address. Ideally, I should have been able to add a home (or other private-use) location, from a point on the map. This functionality does not seem to exist. I do not want an official location, visible to everybody that would be suitable for a business. I want to set a private location and name its address as I wish (because there is an address, used locally).

Can I do any of this? Any ideas?

---

Update-rephrase because "unclear":

In Google Maps, under `My Places` there are some "Labeled" personal locations, one can set, which will be known on all Google products. Among them there is "Home" and "Work" and also the choice to add others. Before there was only the choice to set the address of those "Labeled" places, in some text-boxes (plus some other staff for the place, always in text). Now, there is also a location pointer on the map, which you can move to specific coordinates. The issue has been resolved, just after this post (the next day) and there is an answer already; that is how "unclear" the question was.

[Observe that this update *does not* do anything to "clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need," which is stated, clearly enough, in the original question: (1) "I should have been able to add a home (or other private-use) location, from a point on the map."; (2) "I want to set a private location and name its address as I wish (because there is an address, used locally)". The only imprecision, in my opinion, is that I do not *stress* that the locally used address is a *real address*, despite not being registered and, since my "Home" is a *private* location, it might have been possible to *set* the address itself --and maybe *search* for it! (This second part has not been resolved or answered. I am not sure I like giving such ideas to Google, but someone would eventually...)]

Comment: BTW, I agree that, when not following rules on how to set a question, it is possible that the formulation of the question is imprecise. But this does not mean that when not following the rules, a question formulation *will* be imprecise.

Comment: You can remove the question, since it is fixed now, anyway...

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcHpZ.jpg)ad tha my plase home address google map

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163125)

Answer (score 2):

Have you come across [Plus Codes](https://plus.codes/)? The aim of the whole thing is essentially to provide an "address" to everywhere, regardless of whether or not there is an official street address there.

As far as adding the address of a place to Google Maps, you can use this to create a private place quite easily. First, find the spot on the map. Then, either using the Google Maps app, or the [Plus Codes Map](https://plus.codes/map/), find its code. For instance, I'm going to select the tip of an island on the St. John River:

[image: plus code location]

Note the full code in the sidebar: **87RGQ95V+JP**. It can actually get even more specific, like ...JPX, which is down to individual meters, I believe. But this is specific enough for me.

Back on Google Maps, go into the menu and select **Your Places**. You should be able to set your "Home" address with the Plus Code.

[image: homeaddress]

Go ahead and close "Your Places" and view the map: your home is there!

[image: new home location]

Another method: In Google Maps, simply search that same Plus Code. When the search results pop up, click the option to **Add a Missing Place**. Name it as you like, and supply the Plus Code again in the Address box:

[image: addedplace]

And there it is! Huzzah!

[image: newplace]

*Note that depending on the category you choose, this may or may not be visible to other users*. You may be able to add the locally-used address to the "Name" field, depending on its length. This new place will also be added to the "Your Places" tab.

Comment: So [PlusCodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Location_Code) is the Google equivalent to [what3words](https://what3words.com/), I feel a whole Betamax vs VHS thing coming along...